# Serialize Python object with json.dump

Tags: python, json

An external library calls json.dump() on the object I pass it (which is complex and also has lists of other objects etc.

Can I somehow define inside a class how it is serialized? PHP has http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

Which is called when you run json_encode() on an object (and objects inside the object)

I've read about extending from JSONEncoder and then the default function is called, but this doesn't work (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)

The main problem is I don't have any control what arguments are passed to json.dump() besides the object i'm passing. I can't define a special encoder.

Below an example object I want to serialize and my try of using the JSONEncoder class

```
class FancyObject(JSONEncoder):
    some_value = None
    more_objects_in_a_list = []

    def default(self, o):
        return {
            "some_value": o.csin,
            "more_objects_in_a_list": o.more_objects_in_a_list
        }
```

Here is the encoder that I can't modify https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/serializer.py

Comment: You probably need to define your own serializer object and tell Elasticsearch-py to use it. You can just subclass that `JSONSerializer` and override the `dumps` method, or do it however you prefer. From the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html): "By default, [JSONSerializer](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/serializer.py#L24) is used to encode all outgoing requests. However, you can implement your own custom serializer". There is an example there, just need to pass a `serializer` parameter to the `Elasticsearch` object.

Comment: Hmm that's annoying. But I guess it's the only way.